# Favicon displaying in DeveloperPro Sandbox but not in Partial Sandbox

Tags: digital-experience, favicon

Under **setup > Digital Experience > All Sites > Builder > Settings > Advanced >  Edit Head Markup**  I have the following tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resource/FaviconSite" type="image/x-icon" />
```

FaviconSite is a static resource. When i click the 'view file' I can see the icon.

I can see the favicon in the browser tab when I login to the site from a Developer Pro sandbox.

However when I login to the site from the Partial Sandbox, I don't see the favicon in the on the browser tab.

I have cleared the cache, and waited for 5 hours since publishing the site from the partial sandbox.

Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: Have you tried after republishing the communities/digital experience on partial sandbox?

Comment: Yes Raul I have tried after Re Publishing.
Interestingly it's displaying in two of the sandboxes, both are DeveloperPro sandboxes, but not in this Partial Sandbox.

Comment: Does the communities on partial sandbox has a subdomain: like `.com/partners`?

Comment: You are right.                                                                                                          
 This is the difference between the URL
Partial SB: https://cpcpcpcp--uat.sandbox.my.site.com/something
DeveloperPro: https://cpcpcpcp--qa.sandbox.my.site.com 
What should I do to  display the favicon ?